# How does one get in the Steam mobile app beta?

Tags: steam

Steam recently [released a mobile app](http://store.steampowered.com/mobile).

What is confusing is it doesn't say anything about beta, but when you try out the app it says "Account not part of the beta."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Android app page](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.valvesoftware.android.steam.community) says the beta is now open to all registered Steam accounts.

Answer (score 9):

It is in closed beta right now.

From [the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2504573):

> Those who wish to join the beta just need to download the Steam app
>   (free of charge) and log in to their Steam account via the mobile app
>   to express interest in the beta. Gamers will be added to the Closed
>   Beta as the service ramps up.

So basically, download the app, open it, and sign in. Signing in lets Valve know you are interested in the beta, and if you are lucky, eventually you will be given an invite to the beta.

Comment: I've read that. `Anyone wishing to download the beta just need to download the Steam app and log in to their Steam account via it and apply for the beta. Since the beta is a closed one, gamers will be added on a case by case basis for now and more invites will handed out as the service becomes older.` But what's the source on that? I don't entirely trust 3rd parties.

Comment: @Zeno I changed my answer to include a link from the Steam forums.

Answer (score 0):

I got into the Steam Mobile beta just by signing in, never went to the beta opt-in page.  It wasnt available for my account on the first log-in but it appeared in my Steam gifts shortly afterwards and I was able to log in.

Comment: It isn't a beta opt-in page. You opt in to the beta by signing into the app.